# Android Emulator Windows 7 low fps

Tags: android, windows-7, emulation

I used to have Windows XP on my machine and now i decided to turn to windows 7.
The LunarLander application used to run on windows XP on 50-60fps but now it runs on 20-30fps on windows 7. The hardware configuration didnt change at all.

It seems that it has to do with drivers of video card. I have installed the latest drivers for video card (Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family) but didnt make any differnce.

Does anyone have experience on this issue?

please help

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Intel chips are very slow in general, don't feel bad though I have a Dual Quad Core Xeon processor running @2.8 each core and a NVIDIA Quadro FX 4600 and 8 GB of DDR3 Ram and I still can't figure out why the emulator is so slow... my computer can play any high end new video game at high settings with very good FPS but I can't emulate a phone OS? That's strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

Switch your theme to Aero Basic. That should help.

Comment: Hi, i did it but i didnt noticed any difference. Think about the LunarLander example running on 8fps

Comment: If that didn't make the situation better, then I'd imagine this is an issue with the drivers for Win7 itself.